# Repeat group cell value to detail lines in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

EXCEL 2016:

My excel looks like this:

[image]

I need to repeat the "BDT" or "DEI" text to every detail line ABOVE them.

Every line that has the "G/L Offset" text is a subtotal for the above lines and the number of the detail lines are variable.

I suppose that i cannot do it with worksheet functions and i should do it with a macro?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just use something like this (suppose "BDT" and "DEI" appear in column E, paste this formula C14 and drag up/down)

```
=IF(OR(E14="BDT",E14="DIE"),E14,C15)
```

Comment: I need this to happen automatically with different files and different amount of lines. The first column must be filled with the "relative" values from column E.... I dont know if i am understood...

Comment: From what I understand - the formula does exactly want you want it to. You can copy it to different files and use it for different amounts of lines.